# Why expect does not match as expected?

Tags: tcl, expect

The `expect` does not match as expected from the debugging mode in my case and I don't understand why...

The part of related tcl is like this

```
...
set index 0
set p [lindex $propname $index]
send "prove -property {<embedded>::wrapper.$p}\r"
expect {
  "*proven\r\n\[<embedded>\] % " { 
        incr index
        if {$index == [llength $propname]} {
            send "exit\r"
            expect "*bash-4.2$ "
            send "exit\r"
            close
        }
        set p [lindex $propname $index]
        send "prove -property {<embedded>::wrapper.$p}\r"
        exp_continue
        }

  "*cex\r\n\[<embedded>\] % " { 
        send "visualize -violation -property <embedded>::wrapper.$p\r"
        expect "*\[<embedded>\] % "
        send "visualize -save -vcd cex.vcd -force\r"
        }
}
...
```

From the output of the debugging mode:

```
expect: does "prove -property {<embedded>::wrapper.x0_nouse}\r\nINFO (IPF031): Settings used for this proof:\r\n    time_limit                    = 86400s\r\n    per_property_time_limit       = 1s * 10 ^ scan\r\n    engine_mode                   = Hp Ht N B \r\n    proofgrid_per_engine_max_jobs = 1\r\n    proofgrid_mode                = local\r\n    proofgrid_restarts            = 10\r\nINFO (IPF036): Starting proof on task: "<embedded>", 1 properties to prove with 0 already proven/unreachable\r\nINFO (IRS029): Starting reset analysis: phase 1 of 4.\r\nINFO (IRS030): Running reset analysis phase 2 of 4.\r\nINFO (IRS031): Running reset analysis phase 3 of 4.\r\nINFO (IRS020): Starting the reset analysis simulation with a limit of 100 iterations (phase 4 of 4).\r\nINFO (IRS024): Reset iterations 0 to 4 analyzed.\r\nINFO (IRS018): Reset analysis simulation executed for 3 iterations. Assigned values for 280 of 4626 design flops, 0 of 32 design latches, 136 of 2696 internal elements.\r\nUsing multistage preprocessing\r\nStarting reduce\r\nFinished reduce in 0.192s\r\n0.PRE: A proof was found: No trace exists. [0.00 s]\r\nINFO (IPF057): 0.PRE: The property "wrapper.x0_nouse" was proven in 0.00 s.\r\nFound proofs for 1 properties in preprocessing\r\nINFO (IPF059): Completed proof on task: <embedded>\r\nproven\r\n[<embedded>] % " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*proven\r\n[<embedded>] % "? no
 "*cex\r\n[<embedded>] % "? no
```

Sorry the line is a bit long, but if you scroll to the right most, you will see that the end of that line is exactly what is expected in the first case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing a glob pattern and rightly need to escape the `[]` so that it is not executed by tcl as a command. You need to further escape `[]` so that `[abc]` matches the literal string `[abc]` and not just a character from the set `abc`.

However, when quoting with `""`, the backslash needs to be escaped too, so you need as your glob pattern

```
"proven\r\n\\\[<embedded>\\\] % "
```

As an alternative you can try for an exact match without a glob

```
 -exact "proven\r\n\[<embedded>\] % "
```

You can also use `{}` instead of `""` but then your `\r` and so on will not be converted.